# React Router Link to open in a new tab ask username password

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react app with a view for the existing products. I want to add a link to open the product in a new tab and edit the product. When I click on the link, it opens in a new tab but it ask username and password. Following is the react router link

```
<Link
            to={{
              pathname:
                PATHS.DASHBOARD.SERVICES.PRODUCT_CATALOG_MAIN_EDIT_VIEW,
              search: id,
            }}
            target="_blank"
          >
            <FolderViewOutlined />
          </Link>
```

This link worked in chrome before the update Version 89.0.4389.82

Comment: Does Dashboard routes are password protected?

Comment: New tab/window == new instance of your app running, so you will need to load/initialize state to some more global source of truth, like localStorage. Maybe you can refactor to pass a sort of "authToken" in route state so the receiving route in the new app context can "authenticate".

Comment: @abhay  dasbord router is password protected

Comment: I don't know what your business requirements are, but it may be simpler to open a modal/dialog/etc in the same window context and avoid this issue.

Comment: @DrewReese need to open in a new tab.

Comment: @DrewReese This link worked in chrome. After the new update, it is not working.